# How do you get `pam_succeed_if.so` to recognize `service` user?

Tags: pam

I have a Linux system with a user named `service`. I'm using the `pam_succeed_if.so` module to match this username. For example:

```
auth      required      pam_succeed_if.so user = service
```

But it won't match a username of `service`, apparently because it is also a field accepted by `pam_succeed_if.so`. From the man page (edited for emphasis):

> Available fields are user, uid, gid, shell, home, ruser, rhost, tty and **service**

**How do you escape values that match field names?**

*Further Troubleshooting:*

I turned the `debug` option on for `pam_succeed_if.so`, and it's converting the username `service` to `login`:

```
login: pam_succeed_if(login:auth): 'user' resolves to 'login'
```

And this just so happens to be the PAM config for login, `/etc/pam.d/login`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pam_succeed_if.so` converts the passed-in `user` to the `field` value, if that value exists. For example, using the user `shell`:

```
login: pam_succeed_if(login:auth): 'user' resolves to '/bin/bash'
```

I don't know how to keep it from doing this clearly undesired resolve. But there is a workaround that will work for almost everyone.

Just check for the resolved value, instead of the actual value.

**Examples**

To match the `service` user in the `login` PAM config:

```
auth      required      pam_succeed_if.so user = login
```

To match the `service` user in the `sshd` PAM config:

```
auth      required      pam_succeed_if.so user = sshd
```

To match the `shell` user, whose configured shell is `/bin/bash`:

```
auth      required      pam_succeed_if.so user = /bin/bash
```

Comment: Since this is just a workaround, I will keep this question open for awhile, hoping someone else knows more.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question well enough for an answer, but it's confusing to me that your answer says " ... user = login" while your question/requirement says "user = service".

Comment: @JeffSchaller Do the new examples help?

Comment: It still looks to me like your "service" user is showing up with a username of "login" when it seems to me it should say "service"

Comment: Yep, so this workaround wouldn't work if you have a `login` user you need to consider. In my case, it's not a problem.